# Обособление выражения «к чертям»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Ставится ли запятая: «Схватить телефон, книгу, к чертям(,) захлопнуть дверь, а не закрыть на замок...»? И почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ставится.
....................
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Однозначного ответа быть не может, потому как непонятно, что имеется в виду: *схватить телефон **и** книгу, (всё прочее) к чертям* или *схватить телефон, книгу к чертям.*